# How to have a flexible displayClaims structure?

Tags: azure-managed-identity, azure-ad-verifiable-credentials

1. Data structure of Claims is flat and limited: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/verifiable-credentials/rules-and-display-definitions-model#displayclaims-type.
   I need a richer and extensible structure, for example with custom types and arrays. Is this possible, and if yes, how would you recommend to do so?

Adding more Qs below as Stack Overflow only allows asking one Question every 90 mins:

2. Microsoft Entra is kind-of Level-2 Blockchain platform. How does MS recommend a Level-3 platform be built on top of Entra or any other MS Blockchain solution?
3. How to reference Public Blockchain from Entra / private Blockchain hosted within Microsoft?
4. How to integrate Entra with Active Directory accounts of other Orgs.?
5. How much does it cost to issue a cred (understand that verify is free).
6. Can MS Authenticator be customised, with additional restrictions on verification using Govt. IDs? Will using MS Authenticator remain open for all (as in "open" source)?
7. Is it possible to access a postman collection of APIs for various operations in Verified Credentials, say for listing authorities, CRUD of DIDs, etc? Will be handy to work outside of sample issuer / verifier apps. Thanks!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- could you provide specific examples that you are looking to implement but seem not to be possible at the moment?

As far as your other questions:
2- Entra Verified ID is a platform for to Issue/Request/Verify verifiable credentials develop using open standards. We currently support two trust systems in the platform did:ion that is the layer 2 blockchain as well as did:web which doesn't relay on a blockchain. Integration with other trusts systems would be provided by the platform it self.

3- This is beyond Entra Verified ID. Would be good to post this as a separate question.

4- Entra Verified ID verifiable credentials that contain claims that are coming from the issuer's Azure Active Directory can be easily verified without having to establish federation as this is all based on standards. Verifiers can provide access and establish trust to credentials issued from specific issuers or based on specific schemas.

5- Entra Verified ID is free to use from issuance and verification. Also is available to all subscription tiers of Azure AAD

6- MS Authenticator is managed by MSFT. The Entra Verified ID platform has SDKs that allow developers to create their own wallets

7 - We have a Postman collection with lots of examples. Any particular sample that you would like to see?

Comment: Hey @Juan, Thanks for response. In structure, am looking to add metadata in Claim, like the one in https://www.w3.org/community/reports/credentials/CG-FINAL-di-eddsa-2020-20220724/#example-6 that includes Degree type and name.

Comment: Hello Juan Camilo Ruiz, could you please share Postman collection for getting Auth bearer token, and then using it for Issuing and  Verifying Credential API calls, like the one to create QR codes for both issue and verify, and also to simulate QR scanning using API call?